# Add-Member not working when adding ScriptMethod?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add a `ScriptMethod` to an object. I did it exactly according to the example provided by Microsoft (`Get-Help Add-Member -Examples`), yet it's still not working.

Here's the example they provide:

```
$A = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\test.txt
$S = {[math]::Round(($this.Length / 1MB), 2)}
$A | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "SizeInMB" -Value $S
$A.SizeInMB()

0.43
```

Here's my code:

```
$A = 'someTestText_andSome-more*Text'
$S = {
    $first, $rest = Split-String -String $this
    $first + (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($rest) -replace ' '
}
$A | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name ToCamelCase -Value $S
$A.ToCamelCase()

InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ToCamelCase'.
```

Expected result: `someTestTextAndSomeMoreText`.

I tried Microsoft's example and it works, so why would mine not work?

Comment: What is `Split-String` ?

Comment: Custom function. Basically the same as `.Split()` but it also splits on any non-alphanumeric characters as well as capital letters.

Comment: Don't use `Add-Type`, the first example clearly uses Add-**Member**

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen my bad, that was a typo in the post. I'm using `Add-Member`.

Comment: do `[psobject] $A = 'someTestText_andSome-more*Text'` to wrap the string, then it should work

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that works, but why?

Comment: because the string needs to be wrapped in `psobject` before you can add a member to it (the member is added to that wrapper instance) - `[psobject]::AsPSObject($A)` would also work

Comment: Why is it not necessary for the `FileInfo` objects from the example?

Comment: because it's already an object

Comment: @DougMaurer `[System.IO.FIleInfo]` is an object but `[System.String]` isn't?

Comment: Well technically everything is an object. So someone will have to offer a better technical answer

Comment: Other types are intrinsically wrapped in `psobject` even primitive types. I'm sure @MathiasR.Jessen can answer this better than me but for the time being you already have the solution to your problem ;)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm just trying to understand for my own knowledge, but yes I got my answer thank you!

Comment: I would recommend `Update-TypeData` rather than adding a member to the string instance in this case. Reg. "I'm just trying to understand for my own knowledge", ofc its just that what you're asking is not really documented hehe and pretty hard to explain